# Why am I being told city had no member .sort

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

How do I fix this? I've tried different things

```
struct city {
    let name: String
    let county: String
    let State: String
    let Population: Int
}

let city1 = city(name: "Knoxville", county: "Knox", State: "Tennessee", Population: 186173)
let city2 = city(name: "Clarksville", county: "Montgomery", State: "Tennessee", Population: 152934)
let city3 = city(name: "Nashville", county: "Davidson", State: "Tennessee", Population: 692587)
let city4 = city(name: "Chattanooga", county: "Hamilton", State: "Tennessee", Population: 179690)
let city5 = city(name: "Memphis", county: "Shelby", State: "Tennessee", Population: 651932)

var CityArray = (city1, city2, city3, city4, city5)

func CityLists(List: [city]) {
    city.sort{ $0.Population < $1.Population }
}
```

Comment: You meant `List.sort{ $0.Population < $1.Population }`?

Comment: And you should name your variable and method starting with a lowercase, and your classes/struct with an uppercase. Ie, more or less the reverse that you've been doing...

Comment: Your "CityArray" is a tuple, not an array. An array would be `[city1, city2, city3, city4, city5]`. See the answer from jnpdx for more suggestions for improving your code. (voted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> Why am I being told city had no member .sort

This is because:

- the `CityArray` is not an array, but rather a tuple (because you used parentheses rather than square brackets);
- the `CityLists` is not using the parameter you passed to the method; and
- even if you did change `CityLists` to use its parameter, the `sort` method (which does a “sort in place”, sorting the existing array rather than returning a new sorted array) only works with a *mutable* collections; but your sorting method has a list parameter, which is an *immutable* copy of your array.

So, consider the following (using standard name capitalization conventions):

```swift
struct City {
    let name: String
    let county: String
    let state: String
    let population: Int
}

let city1 = City(name: "Knoxville", county: "Knox", state: "Tennessee", population: 186173)
let city2 = City(name: "Clarksville", county: "Montgomery", state: "Tennessee", population: 152934)
let city3 = City(name: "Nashville", county: "Davidson", state: "Tennessee", population: 692587)
let city4 = City(name: "Chattanooga", county: "Hamilton", state: "Tennessee", population: 179690)
let city5 = City(name: "Memphis", county: "Shelby", state: "Tennessee", population: 651932)

var cities = [city1, city2, city3, city4, city5] // note the square brackets, which make this an array, not parentheses, which would make it a tuple
```

You can either “sort in place” by making the parameter an `inout`, making the parameter mutable:

```swift
func sortByPopulation(_ array: inout [City]) {
    array.sort{ $0.population < $1.population }
}

sortByPopulation(&cities)
```

Or you can write a function to return a new sorted array, leaving the original one “as is”:

```swift
func sortedByPopulation(_ array: [City]) -> [City] {
    return array.sorted { $0.population < $1.population }
}

let sortedCities = sortedByPopulation(cities)
```

---

A slightly more advanced idea might be to add population sorting routines to arrays of cities:

```swift
extension Array where Element == City {
    mutating func sortByPopulation() {
        sort { $0.population < $1.population }
    }
    
    func sortedByPopulation() -> [City] {
        return sorted { $0.population < $1.population }
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```swift
cities.sortByPopulation()
```

Or:

```swift
let sortedCities = cities.sortedByPopulation()
```

This leads to more natural reading code.

---

And, before someone complains about using an `Array` extension (which I did to keep it relatively simple), one probably would define these methods on broader purpose protocols, rather than only `Array` instances. E.g.:

```swift
extension MutableCollection where Self: RandomAccessCollection, Element == City {
    mutating func sortByPopulation() {
        sort { $0.population < $1.population }
    }
}

extension Sequence where Element == City {
    func sortedByPopulation() -> [City] {
        return sorted { $0.population < $1.population }
    }
}
```

This is a slightly more flexible pattern, permitting sorting of any sequence or mutable collection of cities, not just arrays of them.

---

If you’ve followed me this far down the rabbit hole, you might want to see Swift by Sundell’s [Sorting Swift collections](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/sorting-swift-collections/) for other patterns.

E.g., I particularly like the keypath generic pattern:

```swift
extension MutableCollection where Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    mutating func sort<T: Comparable>(by keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) {
        sort { $0[keyPath: keyPath] < $1[keyPath: keyPath] }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    func sorted<T: Comparable>(by keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [Element] {
        sorted { $0[keyPath: keyPath] < $1[keyPath: keyPath] }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```swift
cities.sort(by: \.population)
let sorted = cities.sorted(by: \.population)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here.

1. You should conform to the Swift convention of capitalizing type names and using lowercase names for variables and properties. That will make this less confusing.
2. Your `CityArray` doesn't use array syntax, which uses square brackets
3. You don't use the `List` parameter you send in to your `CityLists` function.

It's unclear whether you want to sort in-place or return an array -- I've chosen the latter in my example:

```
struct City {
    var name: String
    var county: String
    var state: String
    var population: Int
}

let city1 = City(name: "Knoxville", county: "Knox", state: "Tennessee", population: 186173)
let city2 = City(name: "Clarksville", county: "Montgomery", state: "Tennessee", population: 152934)
let city3 = City(name: "Nashville", county: "Davidson", state: "Tennessee", population: 692587)
let city4 = City(name: "Chattanooga", county: "Hamilton", state: "Tennessee", population: 179690)
let city5 = City(name: "Memphis", county: "Shelby", state: "Tennessee", population: 651932)

var cityArray = [city1, city2, city3, city4, city5]

func cityLists(list: [City]) -> [City] {
    list.sorted { $0.population < $1.population }
}
                 
print(cityLists(list: cityArray))
```

If for some reason you wanted to sort in place (not recommended, as it's not very Swift-y). you could do:

```
func cityLists(list: inout [City]) {
    list.sort { $0.population < $1.population }
}
              
cityLists(list: &cityArray)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I make use of the .name part of the City struct so I can only print the name when I call the function?

Comment: cityLists(list: cityArray).map(\.name)